# Webpack plugin: how to read files of plugin consumer at build time?

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-plugin

Is it possible to read the contents of the repo which installed my Webpack plugin?

Essentially, I've written a particular [JS library](https://github.com/mhluska/vue-initializers) which requires the caller to use [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#requirecontext) in their application code to read some files at build time and pass them to the library:

```js
import Library from 'library';

new Library({
  requires: require.context('./foo', false, /\w+\.js$/),
});
```

I would like to take the burden off of the user and just make that `require.context` call inside the library to simplify the API to this:

```js
import Library from 'library';

new Library();
```

However, it doesn't work because the library has no knowledge of when the application code's Webpack build ran.

I've tried writing a Webpack plugin inside the library:

```js
const path = require('path');

class TestPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.beforeRun.tap('TestPlugin', () => {
      console.log(
        `Path where webpack was executed: ${compiler.options.context}`
      );
    });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [new TestPlugin()],
};
```

However, this only gets called when the library itself is built not when the application is built.

How can I move the `require.context` call into the library (which is an NPM dependency) and still have it read the caller's files?

Comment: Just to be clear about what's being asked, you'd like for your npm library to run a plugin during the build of the application it's required in right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. At a higher level, I want the npm library to require some JS files from the application it's required in *at either build or run time*. Using a webpack plugin is one attempt I tried - open to anything that will work.

Comment: Is the directory name a variable? If not, maybe you could use a file-loader for a hard-coded path, and then use a require in the library somewhere, I think it would work at compile time too with the rest of the webpack config: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Comment: EDIT: Actually this answer might be more what you are after with requiring it in a library that may already be compiled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575060/require-js-files-dynamically-on-runtime-using-webpack