# Webpack JS API: output to a local variable instead of creating a bundle.js file

Tags: node.js, api, webpack

Dеar wеbpack gurus.

Is there a way to bundle my project using webpack without writing output to a file, but rather get the resulting bundle module as a variable in my js scope?

Something like that would be perfect:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
webpackConfig.outputFormat = 'localVariable';
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
compiler.compileLocally((err, locallyBundledApp) => {
    const methodResult = locallyBundledApp.someAppMethod();
    console.log('app method result: ', methodResult);
});
```

I was looking for this in [the docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/), but the only compilation output available in js scope mentioned there was `stats`.

My use case: I need to run a jest test that tests a code depending on a non-standard js flavour ([PEG.js](https://pegjs.org/documentation)) scripts. There is a webpack [loader for that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pegjs-loader), but without webpack this code can't be run - so I need to build the project bundle at the start of the test with webpack and then run my test assertions on the compiled bundle.

I can of course output to something like `/tmp/ololo-bundle.js` and then do

```js
const bundledApp = require('/tmp/ololo-bundle.js');
```

but is this really the only way? Can't writes to file system be avoided in a webpack build?

Comment: Somewhat related [Require JS files dynamically on runtime using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575060/require-js-files-dynamically-on-runtime-using-webpack)

Comment: Nah, I ended up writing bundle to the temporary file after all, seems like the simplest solution after all the googling...